# How to remove the active admin sign-up link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin

I don't want to sign-up new user to (active admin) admin panel..so that I want to customize the login page of active admin.

How can I remove the sign-up link from the admin-login page in active admin.

How can I do the same...?

Comment: I found my Answer in the AdminUser model where I just removed the `:registerable,` from

      devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

Thanks...

Answer (score 6):

The question is quite old, but I just came across the same problem. My solution is:

```
mkdir -p app/views/active_admin/devise/shared
touch app/views/active_admin/devise/shared/_links.erb
```

I have also disabled the routes:

```
devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config.merge(skip: [:confirmations, :passwords, :registrations, :unlocks])
```

Answer (score 0):

If this rule applies to all of your admin pages, you could use a different layout file that didn't include the links (or the partial that included them.

You could set a variable in the controller (e.g. `@hide_login`) then conditionally display them (e.g. `<%= link_to("Sign Up", sign_up_path) unless @hide_login %>`)

I have worked on a number of applications where the admin interface is really a separate part of the app, accessible only to internal users, and in this case it can be helpful to put your administrative models/views/controllers in their own namespace ( e.g. `Admin::ManageUsers`) which makes it easy to globally apply certain rules in a `before_filter` (including, possibly defining the default layout).

Answer (score 0):

There are several posibilities to do this as you know you should have a controller (I mostly use AdminController) wich has an index action.

then in de index view there probably is a render partial wich renders the login/sign-up form

you can locate the elemement wich renders the sign-up link.

If you somehow can't find this you can go to your Terminal/CMD
end type

```
grep -lr "sign-up" *
```

this will find the sign-up link somewhere then just delete it or hide it like above message suggests